# Mouse up event not firing with d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to build a d3.js chart where the user can draw a lines with a mouse. I am able to add a transparent rect over a grid and start the line drawing on mousemove but the mouse up event is never detected.

```
  var rect = chartContainer.append("rect")
  rect.attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', 0)
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .style({'fill': 'transparent'})
  .on("mouseup", mouseup)
  .on("mousedown", mousedown);

  function mouseup() {
      console.log("mouse up");
      rect.on("mousemove", null);
  }
```

Code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/fLk405oc/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are drawing the `line` up to the mouse cursor, the `mouseup` event is not occuring on the `rect` but on the `line` itself.  Easiest fix is to just shorten the line a bit so the mouse cursor is not on top of it:

```
  function mousemove() {
      var m = d3.mouse(this);
      //console.log(drawnline);
      drawnline
        .attr("x2", m[0] - 1) //<-- -1 to get mouse on rect
        .attr("y2", m[1] - 1);
  }
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fLk405oc/1/).